# Hermitian Adjoint of Spinor

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, definition, spinors

Say we have a four component spinor $\psi$:
$$
\psi=\begin{pmatrix}\psi_L\\\psi_R\end{pmatrix}
$$
Is the Hermitian adjoint of this:
$$
\psi^\dagger =\begin{pmatrix}\psi_L^\dagger  \psi_R^\dagger\end{pmatrix}
$$
OR
$$
\psi^\dagger =\begin{pmatrix}\psi_L^*  \psi_R^*\end{pmatrix}~?
$$

Comment: Well the second is a 2x2 matrix, so it has to be the first.

Comment: Sorry, edited - question should make more sense now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the first one. This is exactly what the "dagger" does. It transposes the spinor, converting it from a column spinor to a row spinor, and takes every entry to its complex conjugate, i.e:

$$ \psi=\begin{pmatrix}\psi_L\\\psi_R\end{pmatrix} \xrightarrow{\dagger} \begin{pmatrix}(\psi^T_L)^* (\psi^T_R)^*\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}\psi_L^\dagger  \psi_R^\dagger\end{pmatrix} $$

Comment: Note that the spinor is a 4-component one.

Comment: @0celo7, yeah I missed that. Fixed.

Comment: And in the case that $\psi_{L/R}$ only contains 1 element - is the first option true?

Comment: @RobinWang, yes since the transpose of a scalar is the scalar itself.